# Module not found: Can't resolve './AppRoutes'

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm following this react workshop:
https://github.com/spietrek/workshop.reactjs.1/blob/master/presentation/Introduction%20to%20ReactJS%20Workshop.pdf

I'm following all the code but I'm getting an error:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './AppRoutes'...`

Here's the editable project url:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-project

I'm at pg 17/27

Comment: Could you edit your post adding some code please. It seems that `'./AppRoutes` is a wrong path file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put a space before the name of the file `AppRoutes.js` like `<space>AppRoutes.js`.
You have to remove the space to fix that error.

After fixing this also in you project there are some errors due to `Fragment`. I fixed that by updating `react` and `react-dom` packages to version `16.2.0`.

[This](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-project-ztyomx) is a working fork of you project.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that space!

Answer (score 0):

If `AppRoutes` is a `.jsx` file you have to load it with the `.jsx` file extension. Like `./AppRoutes.jsx`